# How SignedXml.CheckSignature verify the certificate

Tags: windows, ssl, certificate

Here I have a question about the principle of SignedXml.CheckSignature.

As we know, if we call the function with verifySignatureOnly = false, it can verify the certificate.

```
[ComVisibleAttribute(false)]
public bool CheckSignature(
    X509Certificate2 certificate,
    bool verifySignatureOnly
)
```

But how can it verify? 
According to my understanding, certificate should be a public key encrypted by CA private key. so CheckSignature can get the CA public key, then decrypt the certificate?
I want to know how it works. Hope some one can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses windows certificate store to build a certificate chain up to trusted root authority. When it is building the chain the method also verifies revocation status of the certificates (usually from CRLs of all authorities in the chain) to check if any of the certificates in the chain are still valid.

If there are links to OCSP in the certificates then the method could prefer to check OCSP status of these certificates but it depends on OS you are using (I think Win Xp didn't use OCSP but win 7+ does it by default).

If any of the checks the method performs fails, i.e. CRL not available or chain could not be built to a trusted root authority or certificate is revoked, then method returns false.

Comment: So CheckSignature can get the root certificate of current certificate, and verify if current certificate is valid?

Comment: It does not get it by itself. It uses CAPI under the hood to do that. But yes, it gets root certificate from windows certificate store.

Comment: OK, THX. so if we can not get the root certificate, then the verification will fail. For example, the certificate is a domain certificate. I sign a file use the certificate, then I copy the file out the domain, and try to verify the certificate. At this time, the verification should always fail, because we can not get the root certificate. Is my understanding right?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. When you remove any certificate (especially root CA certificate) from store then verification will always fail.

Comment: Hi, so it's mandatory to have the certificate in the store? I find it hard to understand the logic behind it, because the 3rd party could revoke the certificate so we need to do stuff manually..

Comment: @Mafti It is reuired to have some kind of store (by default it is windows cert store) where you have root ca certificates that you trust. Intermediate CA certificates can be fetched by following AIA (if present) in each certificate starting from end entity certificate up to root ca. If AIA section is not present then certificate store will be searched for intermediate ca certificate. If any of certificate in the certificate chain will not be found validation will fail. If any of the certificates is revoked validation will fail.

Comment: @Mafti Revocation of (intermediate) CA is not a trivial thing. If a CA certificate has to be revoked then you can not be sure that end entity certificate which this CA issued can be trusted right? Because revocation means that private key of an entity (CA or someone) is not in possession of this entity any more.  Revocation of root CA is most problematic because there is no revocation list. In the case of windows cert store Microsoft will have to remove this certificate from store by means of windows update. In case of i.e Firefox it is a new version of FF.